# iOS App: Should show a specific image at a specific day, but crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to developing iOS apps and English is not my native language, so please excuse any mistakes and my ugly code.

The app I'm trying to create should just display one specific image at one specific day (and change the image if the date changes).
Therefore I implemented an infinite loop in which the date is checked. If it differs from the one the image was changed the last time, the image changes again. The images are named in a "YearMonthDay.png"-scheme (e.g. "20131017.png").

I already googled a lot and got some code together (I know it's pretty ugly), but it crashes everytime.

I would really appreciate any help!

smViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface smViewController : UIViewController {
  UIImageView* mImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;

- (IBAction)contentModeChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)segmentedControl;

@end
```

smViewController.m

```
#import "smViewController.h"

@interface smViewController ()

@end

@implementation smViewController
@synthesize imageView = mImageView;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.imageView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mImageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *oldDateString = @"";

    while(true)
    {
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
        NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
        if([dateString isEqualToString: oldDateString])
        {
        }
        else
        {
            NSAssert(self.imageView, @"self.imageView is nil. Check your IBOutlet   connections");
            UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:dateString];
            NSAssert(image, @"image is nil. Check that you added the image to your bundle and that the filename above matches the name of you image.");
            self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            self.imageView.image = image;
            oldDateString = dateString;
        }
        [dateFormat release];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Where does it chrashes?

Comment: Your `while(true)` loop blocks the main thread and with it all event processing (and eats 100% processor time). You have to learn about timers ...

Answer (score 1):

You should override - (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application in your apps UIApplicationDelegate. Then you will receive a event when date changes and you can remove any loop or timer.

Comment: Oh!I like this one better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is probably because of the while loop. It's blocking your app.

You should use timers instead, something like this:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkDate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

Where you want to check for a new date every 1 seconds (you probably would be fine with higher frequency) and `checkDate` is the method where you check the date and replace the image if needed.